# How to verify the authenticity of GPG4win download file?

Tags: certificate, gnupg, fingerprint, gpg4win

I am attempting to verify that the GPG4win file I downloaded is actually legit. I have access to a machine that has a verified GnuPG installation. I ran

```
> gpg --recv EC70B1B8
> gpg -v --verify gpg4win-2.3.3.exe.sig gpg4win-2.3.3.exe
  Version: GnuPG v1.4.12 (GNU/Linux)
  gpg: armor header: 
  gpg: Signature made Thu 18 Aug 2016 05:20:50 AM EDT using DSA key ID EC70B1B8
  gpg: using PGP trust model
  gpg: Good signature from "Intevation File Distribution Key <distribution-key@intevation.de>"
  gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
  gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
  Primary key fingerprint: 61AC 3F5E E4BE 593C 13D6  8B1E 7CBD 620B EC70 B1B8
  gpg: binary signature, digest algorithm SHA1
```

My concern is that the primary key fingerprint does not match the code signing certificate on their web-site:

> Code Signing Certificate All Gpg4win exe installer files since April
>   2016 are signed with the following code signing certificate:
>
> ```
>   S/N: 1121A3D67EAB28AA86FD85728B57FA62630D
>   Issuer: CN=GlobalSign CodeSigning CA - SHA256 - G2,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,C=BE
>   Subject: 1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#636F64657369676E696E6740696E7465766174696F6E2E6465,CN=Intevation
> ```
>
> GmbH,O=Intevation GmbH,L=Osnabrueck,ST=Niedersachsen,C=DE
>         sha1_fpr: DE:16:D5:97:2F:0B:73:95:F7:D9:1E:DC:1F:21:9B:0F:FE:89:FA:B3
>         md5_fpr: C0:98:08:94:D4:E7:97:3E:9D:F4:18:E4:5E:0A:2E:D7
>         notBefore: 2016-03-30 16:54:41
>         notAfter: 2019-03-31 16:54:41

I am comparing the `sha1_fpr` to the primary key fingerprint. Is that not the right thing to do?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x334.html) and consider testing with the **trust** command accordingly to resolve or perhaps signing the public key with your private key. Research that a bit more if needed maybe a solution you can apply in your case if you confirm and trust this specific key in question.

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing different kinds of signatures. The signature in `gpg4win-2.3.3.exe.sig` is an OpenPGP signature, which you can verify through GnuPG (but Windows has no support for OpenPGP). On the other hand, the code signing certificate (as it gets verified by for example Windows) is an X.509 certificate. This signature is embedded in the `gpg4win-2.3.3.exe` file. If I remember correctly, you should be able to verify it through [`SignTool verify gpg4win-2.3.3.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

While both OpenPGP and X.509 certificates basically rely on the same cryptographic principles (ie. RSA keys), their keys and certificates are not compatible. While you could create certificates from the same RSA key pair, they would still be different and have different fingerprints: different information is included.

An important difference is also the underlying trust system: while OpenPGP relies on a *web of trust* (you're searching for trust paths starting from your own or other trusted and verified keys; you didn't do so yet, thus the message on a non-trusted signature), X.509 uses a hierarchical approach: so-called *certificate authorities* are trusted and allowed to issue certificates for others (here, this is Global Sign).

Comment: those commands were run on linux.. do you mean that gpg4win was signed on windows?

Comment: Not necessarily, I'd rather say the file was signed to be verified with default Windows tools (acually, it was signed using both technologies). This kind of software certificates is also required for drivers and other system software.

Comment: i'm afraid i don't understand what you are saying: you say that the .exe was signed on windows so it isn't using OpenPGP? if that's the case, now that i have gpg4win i should be able to verify the downloaded file correct?

Comment: There are two independent signatures issued on the GPG4win installer: an OpenPGP signature in the `.sig` file, and a "Windows-style" software signature embedded in the `.exe` file. You can verify each of them independently, they're not connected with each other and issues from separate keys using different standards. Choose whatever signature you prefer to verify the GPG4win installer.